# Sharefile API authentication - will pay for assistance

Tags: .net, sharefile

I'm trying to use a basic (GetItemById) method and simply cannot get through the authentication issues.  I have a valid client id and secret as well as an (I think) valid API key but cannot get it to work.  I'll pay for a solution at $100/hour. Environment is VB.Net.

Comment: Did you get it working with Postman? Are you setting the token to the correct header key?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article [ask] about how to ask questions also read this article [mre] about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement. Good luck 